# Selenium error and how to make it work via terminal?

Tags: javascript, linux, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm facing problem running here.

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File("/usr/bin/firefox"));
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);

driver.get(URL);
```

I'm building my **.jar** file in windows and I have to let it run on CentOS 6.0 Linux system.

The program works normally when I run the **JAR** file from Operating System's terminal. It opens default firefox browser and does the required works. 
**But when I run it from terminal, it gives me error . 
I'm unable to find out the exact reason and solve the problem .**

Can anyone help in this issue please. 
Thank you.

I've also left error

```
 ERROR => org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to  binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055; process output follows:
  Error: no display specified

  Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09  19:55:52'
  System info: host: 'agencymonitor.prime-vendor.com', ip: '0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1',  os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-279.5.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_51'
  Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

Comment: "Error: no display specified"  - are you trying to run headless?

Comment: @MarkRowlands I tried it once using HtmlUnitDriver() , but it game me JavaScript error. I'm trying FirefoxDriver() here.
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(binary, profile);
While I run the same code via terminal in cent os , it runs normally.
But if I run it in Putty terminal , it ganerates the above ERROR.